# Spring Can not load Configuration Class when we Call it by Using Java Reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflection, inversion-of-control

I have blocking when bootsrap the Spring by using Java Reflection, so I implement Spring by using Annotation Configuration then I have the following class as Spring Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.jet.reader")
public class QueueReaderConfig {

    @Bean(name = "jetListener")
    public JetReaderListener listener() {
        return new JetReaderListener();
    }

    @Bean(name = "rbtReaderService")
    public QueueReaderService queueReaderService() {
        return new QueueReaderServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

And then bootsrap the Spring by using the following command

```
context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(QueueReaderConfig.class);
rbtReaderService = context.getBean(QueueReaderServiceImpl.class);
```

It's run normally when I running my application by using JUnit or through Main class, but it display error when I running the application by using Java Reflection (The class that wrap that Spring is load by using URLClassLoader)

```
URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + plugin + "!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
...
Class<?> c = Class.forName (className, true, cl);
...
Object instance = c.newInstance();
...
Method loadMethod = c.getDeclaredMethod("load", OED.class);
loadMethod.setAccessible(true);
loadMethod.invoke(instance, param);
```

The script produce the following exception

```
2015-01-08T21:17:43.000+1100 com.jet.reader.executor.JetQueueReaderExecutor 57 (DEBUG):java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.jet.reader.config.QueueReaderConfig
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.jet.godi.GodiAppConsoleMain.execute(GodiAppConsoleMain.java:143)
    at com.jet.godi.GodiAppConsoleMain.executePlugins(GodiAppConsoleMain.java:92)
    at com.jet.godi.GodiAppConsoleMain.<init>(GodiAppConsoleMain.java:42)
    at com.jet.godi.GodiAppConsoleMain.main(GodiAppConsoleMain.java:231)
```

Is anyone has the same experience with me for this case, please share your solution here

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a reflection error. `InvocationTargetException` just wraps the actual exception thrown by the method invoked through reflection. Look up its cause.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik, yes the exeception raised by invoked method when execute context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(QueueReaderConfig.class). Is SpringContext able to load by using reflection? the script is running well when I run by using JUnit and/or MainClass directly.